# Displaying PDF in web browser or adding option to save/open

Tags: html, pdf, browser

I have a folder on my computer, which has an index.html:

```
<a href="mypdf.pdf">PDF</a>
```

And in the folder I also have mypdf.pdf.

I'm trying to make it so that I can have the option of opening the pdf (or saving it) when I click on the link. However, the browser doesn't do anything when I click on it.

How can I do this? What is the html for this?

Comment: Then, unless you are trying on just a single computer, like http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Managing%20file%20types, it can't be changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is actually browser behavior. The only way to force that would be with javascript.